# В чём преимущество symfony HttpFoundation?

Tags: php, post, get

В чём преимущество использования классов таких как `HttpFoundation` в `symfony` над стандартными методами php, `header(что-нибудь)`, или супер глобальными массивами `$_GET`, `$_POST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобные классы - просто удобная обертка для доступа к глобальным переменным или языковым функциям.

Например, в Yii2 можно воспользоваться методом `Yii::$app->request->post('data')` чтобы получить зачение, переданное в $_POST - но при этом выполнится проверка существования элемента массива и в случае отсутствия в массиве $_POST элемента data, возвратится null. Если бы не помощь фреймворка, мне пришлось бы проводить такую проверку вручную - а это съедает время и вообще рутина :)

Кроме того, подобные обертки обычно связаны с другой функциональностью фреймворков - тот же Yii2 автоматически проверяет верность переданного csrf-токена.

Answer (score 1):

Это относится больше к самой парадигме программирования, нежели к конкретному пакету.

Существуют некоторые не очень красивые ситуации, когда случаются откровенные провалы при использовании нескольких библиотек вместе:

- Когда-то Wordpress подчистую очищал $_GET, и получение какого-то "своего" параметра превращалось в пытку
- Если куда-то по ссылке передается $_SESSION, то есть некислый риск, что произвольный код отмодифицирует его и нарушит логику для других программ
- Opencart вручуню защищает $_GET / $_POST, прогоняя его через конвертацию спецсимволов в HTML-сущности (оригинальные массивы он не модифицирует, но боли я наелся все равно изрядно).
- Чтобы протестировать веб-приложение, нужно поднять сервер и посылать реальные HTTP-запросы
- Если по какой-то причине нужно вызвать соседний контроллер (что уже признак плохого кода, если это не HMVC), то для его вызова приходится получать текущее состояние, изменять его и возвращать на место исходное
- Любой код по загрузке файлов с прямым доступом к $_FILES превращается в лапшу за первые пятнадцать секунд

Серебряной пулей против всего этого является атомарное деление функционала на отдельные классы и пакеты, каким и является HttpFoundation. Он отделяет реальное исполнение от установки значений и вызовов методов. Это дает сразу кучу преимуществ, которые рано или поздно вылезли бы при прямом доступе - это и дополнительная абстракция, и возможность сэмулировать окружение для куска кода, который ровно так же использует HttpFoundation, и невозможность библиотек напортачить с глобальными переменными и усугубить жизнь остальным, и разрешение идиотской ситуации с отсутствием парсинга тела запроса при PUT, и легкое внедрение HMVC - подобное деление просто выносит все традиционные проблемы глобального использования общего ресурса за скобки. Как это сделано (у меня есть эм некоторые претензии к инициализации Request) - это уже другое дело.